# Windows program doesn't run when started using sc create

Tags: c++, windows, cmd, system

I have created a program which is supposed to run as Windows service, starting automatically on boot.

Also i have created a starter, which should create a service and then stop.

Starter is ran as administrator.

I call this system command from a starter:

```
system("sc create MyApp binpath= /*full path*/ type= own start= auto DisplayName= MyService");

system("sc start MyApp");
```

Then Windows says that service creation successful.

However, the program which should run as service just doesn't start!

After the "sc start" command the console shows nothing for a while, Task Manager shows "Starting", and later console says

```
"Error 1053: The service did not respond to the start or control request in a timely fashion".
```

I tried running a command like this, showed in another post here on StackOverflow:

```
sc create SERVICENAME binPath= "**cmd /c** c:\programlocation\program.exe"
```

However, then it says:

```
StartService Failed 2: The system cannot find the file specified.
```

So the `**cmd /c**` thingy doesnt work.

How to make it work, and please only Windows native tools, no external programs.

Comment: That `cmd /c` is plain wrong btw. You need to look in the event viewer/add some diagnostic logging to the service to see whats wrong with it

Comment: So is this a program actually written to be a Windows Service, or is it just a plain ole' .EXE, and you *wish* it would run as a Windows Service?
In any case, it seems your problem lies most likely in the actual code of your program, and you've shown none of that.

Comment: Try _not_ to enclose the `cmd /c` portion in between `**  **`...

Comment: Where did you find `binPath=cmd /c` ?  Because there are no circumstances under which that makes sense, and if there's a SO answer saying it does it needs to be removed, or at least downvoted into oblivion. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *could* do something like this:

[Native C++ Windows Service](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/499465/Simple-Windows-Service-in-Cplusplus)

But I'd switch to C++/CLI and port the following code examples from C#:

[System.ServiceProcess.ServiceProcessInstaller](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serviceprocess.serviceprocessinstaller(v=vs.110).aspx)

Or, even better yet, just do the Windows Service part of your code in C# ... it's much easier than rolling your own in C++.